# Creating a gem for cells components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cells

I want to create UI components to enable users to edit data present in a specified structure. I decided to give [Cells](https://github.com/trailblazer/cells) a try, but I need to encapsulate the whole code in a gem, since I want to provide this components as an extension to an existing gem ([criteria_operator](https://github.com/TheFlow0360/criteria_operator)), which is the source of the classes used for the data.

Is this possible? And if yes, how do I start? Normally, cells expects you to create views and models in specific folders of the default rails folder structure. When creating a gem, I only have the lib folder...

If you need any additional information, please just point it out in the comments. I wasn't sure if there is anything useful I could provide.

---

Disclaimer: The gem mentioned was created by me, and this question isn't intended to promote it.

Answer (score 1):

To use another gem- `criteria_operator`, just add it to your gemspec:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency('gem_name', '~> <version>')
```

or add it to your gems's Gemfile.

To have models and views in your gem, you can use [rails engine](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).
Rails engine allow you to wrap a specific Rails application or subset of it inside a gem.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to depend on other gems. So I really have to use an engine? Could you elaborate this further? I've never created one myself...

Comment: Engines are small Rails applications that can be added to another application to provide functionality to it. If you want to have a rails directory structure and add models and views, I think this is what you are looking for


To create a rails engine, just run the following command:
`rails plugin new my_engine --mountable`.

There are a lot of good tutorials on rails engine, you can look into them and see if it matches your use case.

Comment: thanks! I'll try that out and accept your answer if it works